# SQL - Como referenciar tabelas?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, tabela-banco-de-dados, chave-estrangeira

Estou criando uma tela em um programa que usa duas tabelas, por exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE tb1 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(25) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL ENABLE,
      CONSTRAINT "tb1_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE
   );

CREATE TABLE tb2 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(25) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "tb1_ID" NUMBER(25),
     CONSTRAINT "tb2_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "fk_tb1" FOREIGN KEY ("tb1_ID")
      REFERENCES "tb1" ("ID") ENABLE
   );
```

Os IDs é feito `auto increment` então a medida que é inserido algo eles sempre vão de 1 pra 2 pra 3 etc...

Como faço para a coluna `tb1_ID` que é a FK pegar o valor que foi referenciado.
No programa são feitos 2 inserts, finalizado os inserts na `tb1` já é redirecionado para a segunda tabela onde será feito o insert na `tb2`.

Sobre a questão nas duas telas não aparecerão para o usuário da tela botar nada de ID ou `tb1_ID`, claro tem mais campos nas tabelas mas esses são os que importa para essa pergunta, não sei se expliquei direito mas posso dar mais informações se precisar.

Answer (score 0):

Em resumo o que vai precisar fazer é inserir os dados dentro de um bloco de transação e criar os índices para auto_increment;

Esses índices podem ser criados da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tb1_sequence;
CREATE SEQUENCE tb2_sequence;
```

devem obedecer a sintaxe para criação de [índices com auto increment](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm).

Após a criação das SEQUENCES (que é o equivalente ao auto_increment em PL/SQL) será possível fazer o que deseja.

Na prática o que vai precisar fazer é o seguinte:

```
SET TRANSACTION READ WRITE;
INSERT INTO tb1 (id) VALUES (tb1_sequence.nextval);
INSERT INTO tb2 (id, "tb1_ID") VALUES (tb2_sequence.nextval, tb1_sequence.currval);
COMMIT;
```

Repare que estamos utilizando o `auto increment` do indice `tb1_sequence` e nesse índice estamos utilizando duas funções, o `nextval` e o `currval`. Essas são funções para manipular os índices de maneira a gerar valores sequenciais únicos.

Segue a [documentação de referência para as funções currval e nextval](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/server.816/a76989/ch26.htm)

Também será necessário alterar o seu script de criação das tabelas para não ter um valor default, pois assim temos mais controle sobre os valores dos índices no momento de fazer os relacionamentos entre as tabelas.

O novo script DDL de criação das tabelas deve apenas remover a cláusula DEFAULT. O script final ficará da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE TABLE tb1 (
     "ID" NUMBER(25),
      CONSTRAINT "tb1_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
);

CREATE TABLE tb2 (
    "ID" NUMBER(25), 
    "tb1_ID" NUMBER(25),
     CONSTRAINT "tb2_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("ID"), 
     CONSTRAINT "fk_tb1" FOREIGN KEY ("tb1_ID") REFERENCES tb1 ("ID")
);
```